# JAXB XML Custom name Space

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to give custom name space for my xml attributes while "marshaling". I know there are two ways to achieve this. One is overriding the method of "NameSpacePrefixMapper" class which is no more valid if we tend to use package 'javax.xml.bind'  and another way is defining in packege-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
namespace = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0",
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
xmlns = {
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "g",
namespaceURI="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")
}
)
package com.test;
```

This works fine for me but it is giving name space for all attributes like below

```
<g:feed xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <g:title>intersportOnlineshopping</g:title>
    <g:link>http://www.intersport.de</g:link>
    <g:summary>it is a merchantaised online shopping system<summary>
    <g:entry>
        <g:articleID>7611319580577</g:articleID>
        <g:articleTitle>ETIREL Damen Bikinihose »Melly solid«</g:articleTitle>
        <g:size>0</g:size>
    </g:entry>
<g:feed>
```

I dont want that. I want the name space only for attributes which i intend(like below) .

```
<feed xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title>intersportOnlineshopping<title>
    <link>http://www.intersport.de<link>
    <summary>it is a merchantaised online shopping system</g:summary>
    <entry>
        <articleID>7611319580577<articleID>
        <g:articleTitle>ETIREL Damen Bikinihose »Melly solid«</g:articleTitle>
        <g:size>0</g:size>
    </entry>
<feed>
```

How can i do this . Thanks for any great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `@XmlSchema` annotation to only specify the namespace prefixes. Then on the `@XmlElement` annotation for the properties you want to be namespace qualified specify the namespace parameter.

Comment: I have given the annotation @XmlElement(namespace = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0") for only one property. Still the name space is appending to all. How can I limit the @XmlSchema annotaion to specific method

Comment: @user964147 - Did you remove everything from the `@XmlSchema` annotation except the `xmlns` property?